# Bound of sum of cos(kx)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, sequence-of-function

How can I show that for each $x\in (0,2\pi)$, there is a number $C(x)>0$ such that $|\sum^n_{k=1}\cos(kx)|\leq C(x)$, independent of $n$.

I know that
\begin{align}
2\sin(\frac{x}{2})\sum^n_{k=1}\cos(kx)=\sum^n_{k=1}\sin((k+\frac{1}{2})x)-\sin((k-\frac{1}{2})x)
\end{align}

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: @ne3886: I don’t understand what you wrote. The bound explicitly depends on $x$, so little has to happen when you let $x \rightarrow 0$. Also, (for OP) try and write the entire sum of your RHS for small values of $n$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are essentially done. Note that $$\left|\underbrace{\sum^n_{k=1}\left(\sin\left(k+\frac{1}{2}\right)x-\sin\left(k-\frac{1}{2}\right)x\right)}_{\text{telescoping sum}}\right| = \left|\sin\left(N+\frac{1}{2}\right)x-\sin\frac{x}{2}\right| \leqslant  2$$

Thus,

$$\left|\sum^n_{k=1}\cos kx\right|\leqslant \frac{1}{\left|\sin(\frac{x}{2})\right|}$$